# testing rails routes, any shortcuts I'm missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm writing a set of tests for routes for our api controller. I'm curious whether there is a faster way. We have a bunch of urls like this:

routes.rb

```
post '/api/unfollow' => 'api#unfollow', :as => :unfollow
```

/spec/routing/unfollow_routes_spec.rb

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "route to api unfollow" do
  it "should route correctly" do
    {:post => unfollow_path }.should route_to(:controller => "api", :action => "unfollow")
  end
end
```

Does this look like a reasonable strategy? Is it advised to put only a single route per file? I'd rather put all the routes for a single controller in a single file. On the route definition with named routes, is there a way to leave it blank and rails can infer that it is unfollow_path ?

thx in advance

Comment: One file per controller is fine

Comment: thx - looks like that's what scaffold does too